# What is this C-mount lens?

Tags: old-lenses, equipment-identification

I work in a public research institute and on one setup we have the following lens:

[image]
[image]
[image]

It works well and I'd like to replicate the setup, but there is no reference on the lens, not even a brand name. It is C-mount. Can anyone recognize this lens?

It's a pretty old one, It's been on a shelf for years (if not decades). It may not be sold anymore; in this case, can anyone point me out to something equivalent?

Comment: Hello! I am not sure about the exact lens model, but if you search "tv zoom lens 12.5 75mm f1.8" on google, you might find the lens - there are many similar-looking.

Comment: *"research institute and on one setup*"  What set up is that? what is it used for?  Context about what it is attached to and what it is used for may help.

Comment: Are you sure there's also no brand markings on the mount, such as in the third photo [here](https://www.leicashop.com/vintage_jp/fujinon-f-c-mount-1-6-14-84mm-fujinon-tv-zoom-sku32368-45.html)?

Comment: @Kahovius No, I've checked all around, the only inscriptions are those on the pictures.

Comment: @AlaskaMan I was just evoking that to make clear I'm not a photographer and that I did not buy the lens myself. It's a setup to monitor the behavior of fish in a ~30cm-wide tank. I can't really say more since the setup is not published yet.

Comment: Ebay seems to have a few lenses of that specification. None I saw pictures of lacked the manufacturer name.

Comment: @xiota "here's more to publishing than just the setup": this is indeed true in general but with all due respect, this is not really up to you to judge this in this particular case. The fact that the setup is suitable for the task is a totally different question, and as I stated in the question the lens does the job it is supposed to do. The field of view and depth of view are fine and the images are perfect. I don't want to improve the setup, I want to replicate it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about producing photographs, it is about a closed circuit video monitoring system.

Comment: @MichaelC It's a question about a piece of  equipment, a lens. My usage of it is barely relevant to the question, and there may be photographers here that know this lens. Besides, can you tell me what Stack Exchange site would be more appropriate?

Comment: @MichaelC this lens might have possible uses for photography eg on Nikon 1 system...

Comment: @Ratbert [video.SE](https://video.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the comments and for redirecting me to eBay. I found those visually very similar lenses that fit the specifications:

- [Avenir Lens](https://www.ebay.fr/itm/Avenir-TV-ZOOM-Lens-12-5-75mm-F1-8-928536-/222503866553)
- [Navitar lens](https://www.ebay.fr/itm/Navitar-TV-Zoom-Lens-12-5-75-mm-F1-8-Japan-D7423-/153611461017)
- [Toyo lens](https://www.ebay.fr/itm/Navitar-TV-Zoom-Lens-12-5-75-mm-F1-8-Japan-D7423-/153611461017)

It seems that the same lens has been sold by different companies, so my guess is that mine has been sold by a reseller that did not engrave a name on it. It seems it's not sold anymore by any of the three companies cited above, so I'll go with buying one on eBay.

Answer (score 2):

Ir is a zoom lens for 2/3 inch sensors for video recording. This is a consumer model, made in Japan. This would have been Canon, Tamron or Fujinon, at the time this was made in the 1960s. Many names could have been attached to their production overflow.

Don't pay more than $50 for one. If it is to be used on a CS-mount camera then you will need a 5mm spacer ($2 or so).

Good Luck!